# Unknown token errors with osascript

Tags: terminal, automator, automation, zsh

I want to open a new terminal shell in vscode, using a shell script. The command is shift+ctrl+`

I tried the following:

```bash
osascript -e 'tell application "Visual Studio Code" to keystroke "`" using {control down, shift down}'
```

to which I get:

```
53:60: syntax error: A identifier can’t go after this “"”. (-2740)
```

Seeing similar issues on the internet, I tried inserting escape sequences at various positions (next to the ", next to the `) but then get

```
Expected expression, property or key form, etc. but found unknown token
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The `keystroke` command is from **System Events**.

Comment: Well that fixes it!

Comment: If that fixes it, please close your question.